# add localStorage to angularJs module

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

i'm trying to add localstorage in my module angularJs ,i read some tuts but i can't do it.
i want to save value in local so localStorage seemed to me the better way.
here is my code:

```
>var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["favicon"]);//,
> "localStorageModule"]);
>     myApp.controller("appCtrl", [
>       "$scope",
>       "faviconFilter",
>       //"localStorageService",
>       function($scope, faviconFilter ){//, localStorageService) {
>         $scope.bookmarks = [
>           { 
>             title: "CodePen", 
>             url: "https://codepen.io", 
>             category: "web design", 
>             likes: 3
>           },
>           {
>             title: "Youtube",
>             url: "https://youtube.fr",
>             category: "fun",
>             likes: 3
>           },
>           { title: "Google", url: "https://google.fr", category: "web", likes: 3 }
>         ];
>         $scope.increment = function($index) {
>           $scope.likes++;
>         };
>         $scope.addBookmark = function() {
>           $scope.bookmarks.push({
>             title: $scope.site_name,
>             url: $scope.site_url,
>             category: $scope.site_category,
>             likes: 0,
>             favicon: faviconFilter($scope.site_url)
>           });
>           //localStorageService.add('site_name', 'site_url', 'site_category');
>           //$scope.site_name = localStorageService.add('site_name');
>           //$scope.site_url = localStorageService.add('site_url');
>           //$scope.site_category = localStorageService.add('site_category');
>           $scope.site_name = "";
>           $scope.site_url = "";
>           $scope.site_category = "";
>         };
>         // $scope.orderList = "cat";
>         $scope.bookmarks.forEach(function(bookmarks) {
>           bookmarks.favicon = faviconFilter(bookmarks.url);
>         });
>     $scope.deleteBookmark = function(id) {
>       var bookmark = $scope.bookmarks[id];
>       $scope.bookmarks.splice(id, 1);
>         };
>       }
>     ]);
```

where there is // i'm trying to add localStorage.
if someone can help me ...
ps: sorry for the presentation but the code is too long

Comment: What is the `localStorageModule` you are injecting in your app? Why not just inject `$window` into your controller and use `$window.localStorage`?

Comment: instead of `localStorageService.add` you need to call `localStorageService.set` function as per localStorageModule doc  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

To use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Local_storage) in AngularJS, inject `$window` into your controller:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $window) {
    console.log($window.localStorage);
})
```

The AngularJS team recommends the code inject the `$window` service.

> While `window` is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In AngularJS we always refer to it through the `$window` service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.
>
> — [AngularJS $window Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Comment: it's worked [link]https://codepen.io/nathel/pen/LYVLpgM[/link]